# Can't virt-install during the kickstart of the hypervisor

Tags: kvm, qemu, kickstart, libvirt, cobbler

We install physical machines using cobbler/kickstart.

On theses physical machines we need to be sure that one specific VM is installed and will be running on startup, so we tried to install the vm during a kickstart %post section without success so far.

Our first try was dead simple:

```
%post --log=/root/virt.log
service libvirtd start

virt-install ... --import
%end
```

But we had `running in chroot ignoring request` so we tried with `--nochroot` but still nothing.

Any ideas? This is our client request, I'm not even sure this is really compliant with the cobbler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not compliant, and quite probably will not work. I would have cobbler or  some other machine host a prepared disk image (with `sys-unconfig` applied) and a template domxml for libvirt. In the rc.local of the deployed machine, or via cloud-init, just drop in a command to download the image and the xml file, and run `virsh define` against them.

Comment: That's what we will do if there is no other alternative. I'm waiting a few days before marking this resolved, thanks